# Using \detokenize and underscore in combination with \listoffigures

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, detokenize

I've been using a macro `X` similar to

```
\newcommand{\X}[1]{{\ttfamily{\detokenize{#1}}}}
```

to format certain words that may contain an underscore, without having to escape with `\_`.
This worked until I used it in a `\caption`. This results in an error with both pdflatex and lualatex (`! Missing $ inserted.`). Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\X}[1]{{\ttfamily{\detokenize{#1}}}}

\begin{document}    
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{One \X{a_b} Two}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Do I have to use a different / more elaborate solution for `X` or should I just escape the underscores generally? I am more interested in the best practices instead of a very clever hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the command to be robust, otherwise the annotation in the `.lof` file becomes

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces One \texttt {a_b} Two}}{1}%
```

(I changed the syntax from `{\ttfamily...}` to `\texttt{...}`, which is better). As you see, the `\detokenize` has been applied and disappeared.

On the other hand, if you do

```
\newcommand{\X}{}% for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand{\X}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

the annotation would be

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces One \X {a_b} Two}}{1}%
```

and the problem would not show.

Alternatively, use `\protect\X` when in a moving argument.

Comment: As a follow-up:
1. Would you personally use `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `\detokenize` or simply escape the underscores?
2. Is there a situation where `\newcommand` should be used instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand`?

Comment: @apriori I'd use `\_`, to be honest, but I don't know your document that might have hundreds of these. When to use `\DeclareRobustCommand`? Well whenever the command is expected to be found in section titles or captions.

Comment: As for when NOT to use \DeclareRobustCommand or \protect, you cannot use protected macros in \edef or \ifnum.  See the refcount package as an example of overcoming the restrictions on \ref.